how to read data from android device in ubuntu 24.04 desktop using terminal ; with mtp-list error unable to open raw device
in ubuntu 24.04 ; I can see the device in GUI and able to check its content but their address have some mtp:/ prefix and try to navigate using cd but didnt work.

cd mtp://Google_Pixel_7_28241FDH2008AU/Internal%20shared%20storage

so installed mtp-tools after trying other solution
> sudo apt install mtp-tools

now when run

> mtp-list  


which give below output

libmtp version: 1.1.21
Listing raw device(s) Device 0 (VID=18d1 and PID=4ee1) is a Google Inc
Nexus/Pixel (MTP).    Found 1 device(s):    Google Inc: Nexus/Pixel
(MTP) (18d1:4ee1) @ bus 1, dev 6 Attempting to connect device(s)
libusb_claim_interface() reports device is busy, likely in use by GVFS
or KDE MTP device handling alreadyLIBMTP PANIC: Unable to initialize
device Unable to open raw device 0 OK.

attached screenshot

it listt the device but also giving some error but still dont know how to acces it using terminal?
someone can help me which way I can access data using terminal and copy fast rather than using GUI

(Apologies for the poor formatting. I can't see how to put line breaks in a comment.)
Having a vague recollection of seeing USB devices mount under /var/run/, I tried this (1026 being my user id) after connecting my Android phone and enabling "File transfer":
`$ find /run/user/1026/ -name '*mtp*'`  

It returned this (I've truncated the path here):
`/run/user/1026/gvfs/mtp:host=motorola_moto_g_...`  

which I was able to use on the command line.
